# Printing a list from within a list in Go. Loop trouble

Tags: linux, go

Trying to print a list of routes from within a network namespace. The `netlink.RouteList` function requires an `Interface` type. A list of all interfaces is gathered by `LinkList()`.

I'm trying to call RouteList with every interface and print it's output. RouteList returns type `Route` where I'm trying to print the `int` LinkIndex.

It appears as if my loop

```
  for j := range rt {
    log.Printf("Route: %d : %d",rt[j].LinkIndex)
  }
```

Isn't executing for some reason, running another Printf test in there yields nothing.

Why wouldn't this loop be called?

```
func (h *NSHandle) showInts() {
  nh := (*netlink.Handle)(h) //cast required
  int, err := nh.LinkList()
  if err != nil {
      log.Fatal(err)
  }
  log.Printf("Namespace Ints:")
  for i, r := range int {
      log.Printf("%d: %s", i, r.Attrs().Name)
      rt, err := netlink.RouteList(r,-1)
      if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
      }
      for j := range rt {
        log.Printf("Route: %d : %d",rt[j].LinkIndex)
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This was a bad question. Soon after posting I had realised that the array was obviously empty due to the fact that RouteList was being called without the receiver `Handler`. This was fixed by simply:

```
for i, r := range rl {
    log.Printf("%d: %s", i, LinkIndex)
  }
```